# pst-func animation example does not work

Tags: pstricks, animations, animate, pst-func

The following, which is provided in the ***pst-func*** documentation, does not seem to run correctly but I can correctly run the animation in the pdf documentation file. I used *XeLaTeX* to compile it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption,pst-func,animate}

\newcommand{\studentT}[1]{%
\psset{xunit=0.9cm,yunit=9cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-6,-0.1)(6,0.5)
\psaxes[Dy=0.1]{->}(0,0)(-5,0)(5.5,0.45)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!40,opacity=0.4,linecolor=red,linestyle=none]{%
\psline(0,0)(-5,0)\psTDist[nue=#1]{-5}{5}
\psline(5,0)(0,0)}\psTDist[nue=#1,linecolor=red,linewidth=1pt]{-5}{5}
\rput(3,0.3){$\nu = #1$}\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{animateinline}[poster=first,controls,palindrome]{10}
\multiframe{50}{rA=0.02+0.02}{\studentT{\rA}}
\end{animateinline}
\captionof{figure}{Student’s $t$-distribution.}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

All it displays in the generated pdf are the numbers but no axes and no graph and no animation.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I think you have to compile like
`latex test` ---> `dvips test` ---> `ps2pdf test.ps test.pdf`.
pstricks on XeTeX is a subset of that on dvips.

Comment: Thanks @AkiraKakuto. It worked. But why does it not work in MikTex?

Comment: MiKTeX ships with an old Ghostscript, as far as I know. `animate` requires gs-9.15 or newer (if going the `dvips` route).

Answer (score 1):

Documents with **PSTricks** graphics to be animated inside the `animateinline` environment must be built the standard way, that is, along the sequence of commands:

```
latex mydoc
latex mydoc
dvips mydoc
ps2pdf mydoc.ps
```

`xelatex` usually does not produce the desired result.